# Single Signon across domains - no subdomains

Tags: single-sign-on

I need to create a single signon for domain1.com and domain2.com. 
I found only solutions for subdomains or multisites in this forum, but that isn't what I need.

I've found out, that a single signon would be the best for my needs:

**Requirements**

- no subdomains
- no multisite
- both domains are **wordpress** sites
- domains are on different server/webspace/database
- We have FTP access to both domains
- The registration form on domain1.com should not be changed if possible
- User data should send to domain2.com and the user should automatically logged in, after clicking a link on domain1.com

I read also this thread: [cross domain login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342378/cross-domain-login-how-to-login-a-user-automatically-when-transferred-from-one)
But it seems really comlicated.

**Question**

How to create a single signon for this requirements? Are there Plugins or some framework to use?

Comment: This was answered many times that it is not easily possible, and most likely pointless for anything small. If you need SSO either sites needs to be on the same server, preferably in a multisite, or you need to use external SSO provider like facebook.

Comment: You could set up a Central Authentication Service and then use the WP Cassify plugin. https://wpcassify.wordpress.com/
Not so easy, but it works well.